# Understanding ls output

Tags: unix

When I run `ls -lrt` command on a Unix folder , I get the following output

```
MyServer> ls -lrt
total 10
drwxr-x---   3 UnixUser  other        512 Jul 22  2011 FolderA
lrwxrwxrwx   1 UnixUser  other         46 Aug 23  2011 BEA -> ../../../Some/Folder/SOLARIS/BEA
```

I am not sure what is BEA in these folders. They do not seem to be files nor folders. Why is there a arrow besides them pointing to somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file in question is a **symbolic link**. The symbolic link is another name that "points to" the real file.

When you do `ls -l` it also shows you which file is pointed to by the link. You can actually see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx
^
|________ `l` here means a link
```

Answer (score 11):

BEA and Perlx.x in these folders are symbolic links. The symbolic link is another name that "points to" the real file.

The option `-l` tells the command to use a long list format. It gives back several columns wich correspond to:

1. Permissions
2. Number of hardlinks
3. File owner
4. File group
5. File size
6. Modification time
7. Filename

The first letter in the permissions (`lrwxrwxrwx`) column show the file's type. **`l` here means a link**, A `d` means a directory and a `-` means a normal file (there are other characters, but those are the basic ones). The next nine characters are divided into 3 groups, each one a permission. Each letter in a group correspond to the read, write and execute permission, and each group correspond to the owner of the file, the group of the file and then for everyone else.

```
[ File type ][ Owner permissions ][ Group permissions ][ Everyone permissions ]
```

The characters can be one of four options:

```
r = read permission
w = write permission
x = execute permission
- = no permission
```

Finally, the `+` at the end means some extended permissions.

Comment: for more details: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/linux-ls-command-examples/

Answer (score 1):

These are called `symbolic links` in linux (shortcuts in windows)

When you work on them, for eg `vim BEA` , you will be editing the actual file in  `../../../Some/Folder/SOLARIS/BEA`

Comment: "shortcuts" in Windows have nothing in common with UNIX (symbolic or hard) links. UNIX symbolic links are rather comparable to [Windows/NTFS links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link).

Comment: Okay, what I understand here is windows shortcuts are a superset of linux symbolic links. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)